# SwiftUI: How do I make a View update simultaneously while a function is calculating @State value?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, state

I have a simple counter view with a button that triggers the counting function. The variable `count` has a `@State` property, which should trigger the update of the view whenever the value changes inside the for loop. However, when I press the button, the view updates only after the function finishes executing.

How do I make it so that each step of the `for` loop calculation is reflected to the view?

Thanks in advance!

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var count: Float = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
       
       VStack {
            Text("\(count)")
            
            Button(action: {
                startCount()
            }) {
                Text("Start Count")
            }.padding()
        }
    }
    
    func startCount() {
        for _ in 0...10000 {
            count += 0.0001
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You calculate synchronously. 2. Even if you would not, 10k cycles for modern processors is negligible comparing to time of UI update, so even with async call you'll get final result immediately, if not introduce artificial delays.

Answer (score 0):

A loop is too fast. If you want to slow it and want to show on your screen use the following code. Here I used one global queue to do the background task and when the main queue is available to process, I use it to update the count. Also, I added a `sleep(1)` method to sleep the process.

```
func startCount() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        for _ in 0...10000 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                count += 0.0001
                print(count)
            }
            sleep(1)
        }
    }
}
```